# How to access a protected spring boot resource with access_token from command line , e.g. curl or httpie

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, openid, mitreid-connect

In our spring boot application we use mitreid for openid connect. If we access a protected resource from browser, we are redirected to keycloak, our openid provider,  and then after successful authentication, to the desired resource. This is working like intended.

Now we want to access the same resource from command line, e.g curl or httpie.

But nothing is working.

Getting access_token from keycloak returns an jwt with access_token and id_token.

But access with curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 'access_token>'" http://localhost:8080 doesn't work.

Here is my oidc configuration

```
public class OIDCSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OIDCSecurityConfiguration.class);
private final String loginPath = OIDCAuthenticationFilter.FILTER_PROCESSES_URL;

@Value("${oidc.issuer-uri}")
private String issuerUri;

@Value("${oidc.client-uri}")
private String clientUri;

@Value("${oidc.client-id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${oidc.client-secret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${oidc.client-scopes}")
private String clientScopes;

private String getLogoutUri() {
    final ServerConfiguration serverConfiguration = serverConfigurationService().getServerConfiguration(issuerUri);
    if (serverConfiguration == null) {
        LOG.error("OpenID Connect server configuration could not be retrieved");
        return "/";
    }
    try {
        return serverConfiguration.getEndSessionEndpoint() + "?redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode(clientUri, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        LOG.error("Cannot encode redirect uri");
        return "/";
    }
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/openid_connect_login")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl(getLogoutUri());
}

@Autowired
public void configureAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(loginPath);
}

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter mvcInterceptor() {
    return new UserInfoInterceptorAdapter();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    final OIDCExtendedAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OIDCExtendedAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setAuthoritiesMapper(new KeycloakAuthoritiesMapper(clientId));
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    final OIDCAuthenticationFilter filter = new OIDCAuthenticationFilter();

    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filter.setServerConfigurationService(serverConfigurationService());
    filter.setClientConfigurationService(clientConfigurationService());

    final StaticSingleIssuerService issuer = new StaticSingleIssuerService();
    issuer.setIssuer(this.issuerUri);

    filter.setIssuerService(issuer);
    // TODO: change to signed or encrypted builder for production.
    filter.setAuthRequestUrlBuilder(new PlainAuthRequestUrlBuilder());
    return filter;
}

@Bean
public ClientConfigurationService clientConfigurationService() {
    final StaticClientConfigurationService service = new StaticClientConfigurationService();
    final RegisteredClient client = new RegisteredClient();
    client.setClientId(clientId);
    client.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    client.setClientName(clientId);
    client.setScope(Arrays.stream(clientScopes.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    client.setTokenEndpointAuthMethod(AuthMethod.SECRET_BASIC);
    client.setRedirectUris(Collections.singleton(clientUri + loginPath));
    client.setRequestObjectSigningAlg(JWSAlgorithm.RS256);
    service.setClients(Collections.singletonMap(this.issuerUri, client));
    return service;
}

@Bean
public ServerConfigurationService serverConfigurationService() {
    final DynamicServerConfigurationService service = new DynamicServerConfigurationService();
    service.setWhitelist(Collections.singleton(issuerUri));
    return service;
}

private static class UserInfoInterceptorAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new UserInfoInterceptor());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: After "..Bearer" there should go some token value (ideally the one u got from access provider) ..terminated by a `;` ...and in gerneral: you should imitate with curl/httpie as similar/same as possible request as in browser.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @xerx593   my curl command was correct. In the post i had the forgotten to mention the token.

Comment: @punkrocker27ka The error i receive from spring boot is: Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point. The JWT isn't not processed.

Comment: @luka-m In this case I would set some breakpoints in spring-security-oauth, specifically [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtAccessTokenConverter.java#L116)  You should then be able to verify if the token string is present, if it can parse it successfully, and so on.  Find out where the Exception occurs.  Enable debug logging for Spring Security, it will be very helpful when debugging.  If you need additional help, please share the Exception Logs.  Thanks.